# Vuforia Unity - Detect Image Target only if its highly accurate

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Vuforia detects image targets even if it matches partially.

So, Vuforia has this Star ratings and it detects the image target if it somewhat matches.
What I want to do is if there is any method I can use in Vuforia to put an accuracy threshold...like only detect it when its 90% or more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It it not clear which type of target you are using however Vuforia Engine is designed to detect and track targets even when partially occluded. As a side effect this means that the Engine cannot distinguish between objects which differ only in some details.

At the moment there is no way to tune the algorithm for accuracy. If you have a good use case for detecting similar objects you can file a feature request here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine